# Get WP7 battery telemetry data?

Tags: windows-phone-7, power-management, telemetry

I'm looking for a way to get the current battery telemetry under Windows Phone 7. The closest part of the framework looks like `Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue()` but it seems you can only query the device info (model, serial) and the current memory consumption.

Is battery data inaccessible under this iteration of WP7 SDK, or am I just missing something?

Comment: the windows-mobile tag is not appropriate for this question. WP7 and WM are two distinctly different architectures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API at the moment for this.